# Returning values from a column based on the last value of another column

Tags: r, dataframe, max, rows, data-cleaning

I have a dataset like this:

```
data <- data.frame(Time = c(1,4,6,9,11,13,16, 25, 32, 65),
                  A = c(10, NA, 13, 2, 32, 19, 32, 34, 93, 12),
                  B = c(1, 99, 32, 31, 12, 13, NA, 13, NA, NA),
                  C = c(2, 32, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

What I want to retrieve are the values in `Time` that corresponds to the last numerical value in `A`, `B`, and `C`. 
For example, the last numerical values for `A`, `B`, and `C` are 12, 13, and 32 respectively.

So, the `Time` values that correspond are 65, 25, and 4.

I've tried something like `data[which(data$Time== max(data$A)), ]`, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can multiply the `row` index with the logical `matrix`, and get the `colMaxs` (from `matrixStats`) to subset the 'Time' column

```
library(matrixStats)
data$Time[colMaxs((!is.na(data[-1])) * row(data[-1]))]
#[1] 65 25  4
```

---

Or using `base R`, we get the index with `which/arr.ind`, get the `max` index using a group by operation (`tapply`) and use that to extract the 'Time' value

```
m1 <- which(!is.na(data[-1]), arr.ind = TRUE)
data$Time[tapply(m1[,1], m1[,2], FUN = max)]
#[1] 65 25  4
```

---

Or with `summarise/across` in the devel version of `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    summarise(across(A:C, ~ tail(Time[!is.na(.)], 1)))
#    A  B C
#1 65 25 4
```

Or using `summarise_at` with the current version of `dplyr`

```
data %>%
     summarise_at(vars(A:C), ~ tail(Time[!is.na(.)], 1))
```

Comment: Thank you Akrun. Using the dot in `!is.na(.)` tells R to use all the variables in the data frame, right (A:C) in this case?

Comment: @Mcmahoon89 The `~` is a shortcut for `function(x)` with `across` we are looping over each of the columns similar to `lapply(data[-1], function(x) !is.na(x))`. In tidyverse terminology, the `~` replaces the function(x) and `x` is replaced with `.` which is basically the vector of values of each column

Comment: @Mcmahoon89 I read your other comment.  It is basically practise and of course following certain simple things each day.

Comment: Hi Akrun, how do we get access to the across() function. It doesn't seem to be available in my dplyr package.

Comment: @Drew sorry, i was using the devel version of dplyr.  Thought, that the new CRAN version 1.0.0 also included that

Comment: @akrun Ah I see. Your second (Base R)  solution worked for me, btw, so thank you. Is it possible for you to update the dplyr solution using the functions available in the new CRAN version? The dplyr one makes sense to me intuitively, and would love to see a solution there that doesn't require across()

Comment: @akrun Great. Thank you!